# expressJS/jestJS: How to split get() function to write simple jest unit test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, express, jestjs

How do I define a get() routing in an expressJS application with the intention of doing easy unit testing?

So as a first step I moved the function of `get()` in an own file:

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const socketIo = require('socket.io')
const Gpio = require('pigpio').Gpio

const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketIo(server)

const setStatus = require('./lib/setStatus.js')

app.locals['target1'] = new Gpio(1, { mode: Gpio.OUTPUT })

app.get('/set-status', setStatus(app, io))
```

**lib/setStatus.js**

```
const getStatus = require('./getStatus.js')

module.exports = (app, io) => {
  return (req, res) => {
    const { id, value } = req.query // id is in this example '1'
    req.app.locals['target' + id].pwmWrite(value))
    getStatus(app, io)
    res.send({ value }) // don't need this
  }
}
```

**lib/getStatus.js**

```
const pins = require('../config.js').pins

module.exports = async (app, socket) => {
  const res = []
  pins.map((p, index) => {
    res.push(app.locals['target' + (index + 1)].getPwmDutyCycle())
  })
  socket.emit('gpioStatus', res)
}
```

So first of all I'm not quite sure, if I split that code correctly - thinking of doing unit testing.

For me the only thing which has to be done by calling `/set-status?id=1&value=50` is to call `pwmWrite()` for an (I guess) object, which is defined by `new Gpio` and stored in `locals` of expressJS.

And for the second: If this should be the correct way, I do not understand how to write a jestJS unit test to check if `pwmWrite` has been called - which is inside of an asyncronous function.

This is my attempt, but I can't test for the inside call of pwmWrite:

```
test('should call pwmWrite() and getStatus()', async () => {
  const app = {}
  const io = { emit: jest.fn() }
  const req = {
    app: {
      locals: {
        target1: { pwmWrite: jest.fn() }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  expect.assertions(1)
  expect(req.app.locals.target1.pwmWrite).toHaveBeenCalled()
  await expect(getStatus(app, io)).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Comment: well, `app.locals['target1'].pwmWrite = jest.fn()` ?

Comment: codebase seems to be ok, not clear where your test does the actual call of `setStatus`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close, just missing a few things.

You need to call the methods `setStatus` and `getStatus` before the expect statements,
and you were missing mocks on `req.query` and `res`, since `getStatus` uses them.

```
test('should call pwmWrite() and getStatus()', async () => {
  const app = {}
  const io = {};
  const req = {
    query: {
      id: '1',
      name: 'foo'
    },
    app: {
      locals: {
          target1: { pwmWrite: jest.fn() }
      }
    }
  };
  const res = { send: jest.fn() };

  // Mock getStatus BEFORE requiring setStatus
  jest.mock('./getStatus');

  //OBS Use your correct module paths
  const setStatus = require('./setStatus');
  const getStatus = require('./getStatus');


  // Call methods
  setStatus(app, io)(req, res);

  expect.assertions(2);

  // Get called in setStatus
  expect(req.app.locals.target1.pwmWrite).toHaveBeenCalled();

  // See if mocked getStatus has been called
  await expect(getStatus).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The `getStatus` needs to be mocked before requiring `setStatus`, since its used there

Comment: I was thinking of a mock for `getStatus()` as I only want to call `setStatus` and test if `getStatus` has been called. I don't want to test for the emit event.

Comment: could you include the `getStatus` method in your question above @user3142695?

Comment: If added the code in the question. But this part is handled by an own test. As I'm trying to do unit testing, I'm testing it seperatly. So `setStatus` should not go into `getStatus` at all, but only should test if `expect(getStatus).toHaveBeenCalled()` - whatever there is happening.

Comment: @user3142695, I think I got it!

Comment: why do I have to call the mock first?

Comment: `Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called` for `await expect(getStatus).toHaveBeenCalled()`

Comment: you only call 'setStatus', and test that the 'getStatus' mock has been called. You need to trigger a function invocation to be able to test that the mocks are hit

Comment: which version of jest are you using @user3142695? I've got it working with jest@23.6.0, node@8.12.0. Remember to copy my code again, since I edited it since last time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182491/discussion-between-lazreg87-and-user3142695).